# Does the video Experiments in the Revival of Organisms depict genuine results?

Tags: medical-science, history, video, experiments

The video in question, which is in the public domain.  Warning: may contain disturbing imagery.

http://archive.org/details/Experime1940

The 20 minute 1940 Russian video purports to show the results of early experiments by Doctor Sergei Brukhonenko in artificially sustaining biologic life and brain functions.  At one point the decapitated head of a canine is shown artificially kept alive, reacting to stimuli as though conscious.  There is no doubt that Doctor Sergei Brukhonenko performed the experiments and that he contributed significantly to the medical field with them.  However, many claim the video is not genuine, but instead is a special effects recreation of the experiments and does not therefor show accurately the results of the experiments.

Are the events of the video genuine, or are they a recreation?

Comment: Woo hoo!  Question 4000!

Comment: Isn't this question related it it http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/is-the-video-of-soviet-dog-revival-experiment-real

Comment: Yes,quite.  I just happened to ask it six months earlier.